# Asynctask SerialExecutor is not serially executing

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have created the following 2 Asynctasks

```
public class MyAsynctaskWithDelay extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(arg0[0] + "before sleeping of AsyctaskWithDelay..");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(arg0[0] + "after sleeping of AsyctaskWithDelay..");
        //System.out.println(arg0[0]);
        return null;

    }

}
```

AND

```
public class MyAsynctaskWithNoDelayLoop extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(arg0[0] + " The task with no delay...");
        //System.out.println(arg0[0]);
        return null;

    }
}
```

And then in the main activity i have done like the following:

```
        MyAsynctaskWithDelay asynctask1 = new MyAsynctaskWithDelay();
        MyAsynctaskWithDelay asynctask2 = new MyAsynctaskWithDelay();
        MyAsynctaskWithNoDelayLoop asynctask3 = new MyAsynctaskWithNoDelayLoop();
        MyAsynctaskWithNoDelayLoop asynctask4 = new MyAsynctaskWithNoDelayLoop();


        asynctask1.execute("Asynctask 1");
        asynctask2.execute("Asynctask 2");
        asynctask3.execute("Asynctask 3");
        asynctask4.execute("Asynctask 4");
```

Hence according to the definition of SerialExecutor, the task should be executed in accordance to the sequence in which the execute method is called and the background task should not be preempted.

However, I have run this application and got the following result.

```
12-02 09:18:20.526: I/System.out(402): Asynctask 1before sleeping of AsyctaskWithDelay..
12-02 09:18:20.576: I/System.out(402): Asynctask 2before sleeping of AsyctaskWithDelay..
12-02 09:18:20.586: I/System.out(402): Asynctask 3 The task with no delay...
12-02 09:18:20.586: I/System.out(402): Asynctask 4 The task with no delay...
12-02 09:18:30.582: I/System.out(402): Asynctask 1after sleeping of AsyctaskWithDelay..
12-02 09:18:30.703: I/System.out(402): Asynctask 2after sleeping of AsyctaskWithDelay..
```

As it is clear that the first two tasks have been preempted while inside the doinbackground method which was obviously not expected.

Please clarify my doubts so that I can answer my own questions on how Asynctask Serialexecutor works.

If we delve into the source code of the Serial Executor class of Android we will find

```
 private static class SerialExecutor implements Executor {
        final ArrayDeque<Runnable> mTasks = new ArrayDeque<Runnable>();
        Runnable mActive;

        public synchronized void execute(final Runnable r) {
            mTasks.offer(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        r.run();
                    } finally {
                        scheduleNext();
                    }
                }
            });
            if (mActive == null) {
                scheduleNext();
            }
        }

        protected synchronized void scheduleNext() {
            if ((mActive = mTasks.poll()) != null) {
                THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.execute(mActive);
            }
        }
    }
```

If we look at the following part of the execute function as written as

```
 mTasks.offer(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            r.run();
                        } finally {
                            scheduleNext();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

we will know that every time an execute function is called it is creating a new thread and inside that thread it is executing the background task. That means any long running background task can be preempted by another execute's background task of a different Asynctask instance. Then why it is called Serial Executor.

Comment: I don't see you using the `SerialExecutor` in any way..

Comment: As you know the default executor is Serial Executor

Comment: I have got some of my doubts cleared. As the SERIAL-EXECUTOR is a final static field, it will be shared by all the objects of the same Asynctask. Along with this is Synchronized keyword before the execute function. Hence it works as a serialexecutor. However, from the result of my Android app, we can see that some of the background tasks are being preempted... please enlighten me with your explanations...

Comment: i got it. my minSDKversion was 8. i have now made it 14. and its working fine. sorry for accusing Android framework without correcting myself...

Comment: Here goes my discussion on Android Asynctask Internal vis-a-vis Half Sync Half Async pattern... https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_zihWXAwgTAdJc013-bOLUHPMrjeUBZnDuPkzMxEEj0/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncTask` are sort of easy alternative of threads. So likewise threads (whether serial executer or not) you should not depend on their sequence of execution. If you just have to make them serial then you have to handle that all by yourself.

Comment: are you sure with your comment? i think Asynctask has wrapped the threading issues pretty nicely... its an important part of Android framework as well....

Comment: I'm not saying AsyncTask is bad I'm saying execution of threads are independent from each other.